# RabbitMQ Java API queuePurge() method called on Qpid returns PurgeOK response with zero message count

Tags: java, junit, rabbitmq, qpid

I am integration testing a component that uses RabbitMQ client (amqp-client version 5.7.0) with an embedded Apache Qpid server object.

When calling the `Channel.queuePurge()` method, the queue is purged. I can verify that with the `getMessageCount()` method. But the `queuePurge()` method returns a `PurgeOk` object, which always has 0 message count. The documentation says the `PurgeOK` returns the message count that was purged.

```
   //The queue has 1 message.
   int f = getMessageCount();
   //verify message count
   assertEquals(f, 1);
   //purge
   com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.Queue.PurgeOk purgeOK= channel.queuePurge(queueName);
   //the next test fails.
   //Shouldn't the purgeOK have count 1, to denote that one message was purged?
   assertEquals(purgeOK.getMessageCount(), 1);
```

This happens only when testing with embedded Qpid server. The same test case with an actual running instance of Rabbit MQ is giving the expected.

Is this a known issue? Is there a better way to unit test the purge feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't a *known* issue, I have raised [an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-8318) for this defect in Qpid Broker-J.  Thank you for your help in discovering this.